# Smoothing motion parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing, smoothing, image-stabilization

I have been working on video stabilization for quite a few weeks now. The algorithm I'm following basically involves 3 steps :- 

1. FAST feature detection and Matching 
2. Calculating affine transformation (scale + rotation + translation x + translation y ) from matched keypoints 
3. Smooth motion parameters using cubic spline or b-spline.

I have been able to calculate affine transform. But I am stuck at smoothing motion parameters. I have been unable to evaluate spline function to smooth the three parameters.

Here is a graph for smoothed data points
[image: Here is a graph for smoothed points]

Any suggestion or help as to how can I code to get a desired result as shown in the graph?

Comment: This doesn't answer you question but, if you haven't seen it, it might be of interest - [First-Person Hyperlapse Videos](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/hyperlapse/).

Comment: opencv does not have splines, but a [KalmanFilter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#kalmanfilter) might fit as well

Comment: I could use KalmanFilter but I can't compromise on time. That's why I had to opt for splines

Comment: If you have problem with splines try Gauss smoothing or any other average-type convolution -- it is well implemented in openCV. I doubt you will see a huge difference in stabilization.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that calculate the points on the curve 
[B-spline Curves](http://www.nar-associates.com/nurbs/c_code.html#chapter3)

But now the code will use all control points as transform parameters to formulate.
I think i will run in post-processing (not real time).

Did you run B spline smoothing in real time?

Comment: I wanted to use B-splines in real time. But I couldn't find any real time implementation.